# USA map projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I know that this issues has been discussed, and I indeed find information on this forum and try the suggestions out.

It is about the projection of the USA map shapefile in QGIS. I downloaded the shapefile from https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html, and the map stretched out (squished). It looks wider than it should be.

the map is as below
[image]

So I tried different projections, including EPSG:102003 USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic, EPSG:102004 USA_Contiguous_Lambert_Conformal_Conic and EPSG:102005 USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic, but the map still looks very squished.

I re-wrote the projection file with .txt extension and opened and read it. It showed

```
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]cb_2017_us_state_5m_prj.txt (END)
```

Is it possible I still miss some important steps?

Comment: Have you enabled `on the fly reprojection`? Simply sounds like you're trying to project the data wrongly.

Comment: Link to the QGIS documentation for enabling on the fly reprojection or for saving a dataset to a different projection: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html

Comment: What Q&As from this site did you review and find wanting when trying to find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This particular layer is in the CRS `EPSG:4269 - NAD83 - Geographic`. QGIS should automatically figure that out when you load it into your project. **Don't change the CRS in the layer properties.**

It appears "squished" because it's in a different projection than you're used to looking at. **There's nothing wrong with the data. You're just not used to seeing maps in this projection.**

You're probably used to online maps like Google Maps. Google Maps uses the CRS `EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator`. If you want your map to look like Google Maps, change the **project CRS** to `EPSG:3857`. QGIS will automatically reproject all the layers in your map "on-the-fly", without modifying the source data.

1. Click on the project CRS in the bottom-right corner of the QGIS window. 
   [image]
2. Select EPSG:3857 from the Project Properties | CRS window; click OK.

   [image]
3. QGIS will automatically reproject all the layers in your map "on-the-fly". The map should look normal to you now. If it doesn't, return to step 1 and try different CRS's until you find one that looks right to you.

   [image]